VBA unable to populate data for multiple years
Okay so I am writing a VBA and the issue I am facing is, I have created an object in which we give 2 inputs to calculate, 1 of them is year, it gets the data for year added as input correctly but when I try to map the data of year before input year, nothing is printed
So for example if year is entered 2022 I get data for 2022 but not for 2021, but when I enter year 2021 I get data for 2021
So for line wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 11 + colOffset).Value = accountDict(jurisdiction & yearInput) data is printed but I get null for line wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 12 + colOffset).Value = accountDict(jurisdiction & prevYear)
Sub ImportData_DisaggAvg(filePath As String, yearInput As String, yearMode As Integer, sourceTabName As String)
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsAjes As Worksheet
    Dim sourceFileName As String
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim lastRowSource As Long
    Dim lastRowTarget As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim fileNameParts() As String
    Dim serialNumber As String
    Dim companyName As String
    Dim projectName As String
    Dim accountDict As Object
    Dim accountKey As String
    Dim yearSum As Double
    Dim uniqueJurisdictions As Collection
    Dim uniqueJurisdictionsAjes As Collection
    Dim jurisdiction As Variant
    Dim yearColumn As Long
    Dim yearColumns As Collection
    Dim yearValue As Variant
    Dim firstNonEmptyRow As Long
    Dim headerRow As Long
    Dim headerRow1 As Long
    Dim yearCol1 As Long, yearCol2 As Long
    Dim ajesRow As Long
    Dim ajesLastRow As Long
    Dim ajesYearValue As Double
    Dim CERow As Long
    Dim CELastRow As Long
    Dim CEYearValue As Double

    ' Set the target worksheet
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("output") ' Adjust if your target sheet is different

    ' Extract the filename from the path
    sourceFileName = Mid(filePath, InStrRev(filePath, "\") + 1)

    ' Split the filename into parts
    fileNameParts = Split(sourceFileName, "_") ' Split by underscore

    ' Extract the parts
    serialNumber = Left(fileNameParts(0), 2) ' Extract the first two characters as serial number
    companyName = Mid(fileNameParts(0), 3) ' Extract from the third character as company name
    projectName = fileNameParts(1) ' Project name is the second part after the serial number

    ' Open the source workbook
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(filePath)

    ' Set the source worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets(sourceTabName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Find the last row of the source data
    lastRowSource = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    ' Find the last row in the target worksheet
    lastRowTarget = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    ' Initialize dictionary to store sum of Column N for each account in Column C
    Set accountDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set uniqueJurisdictions = New Collection
    Set uniqueJurisdictionsAjes = New Collection
    Set yearColumns = New Collection

    ' Find the first non-empty row
    firstNonEmptyRow = 1
    Do While WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsSource.Rows(firstNonEmptyRow)) = 0
        firstNonEmptyRow = firstNonEmptyRow + 1
    Loop

    ' Find the column that matches the yearInput in the first non-empty row
    yearColumn = 0
    For i = 1 To wsSource.Cells(firstNonEmptyRow, wsSource.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If wsSource.Cells(firstNonEmptyRow, i).Value = yearInput Then
            yearColumn = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    ' Check if the yearColumn was found
    If yearColumn = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Year " & yearInput & " not found in the first non-empty row of the source worksheet.", vbCritical
        wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Store all year columns starting from the yearInput column
    For j = yearColumn To wsSource.Cells(firstNonEmptyRow, wsSource.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If Not wsSource.Cells(firstNonEmptyRow, j).Value Like "*difference*" Then
            yearColumns.Add j
        End If
    Next j

    Dim prevYear As String
    prevYear = 2021  ' Get the previous year as a string
    ' Loop through the source data and calculate the sum for each year column for each account in Column C
    For Each yearValue In yearColumns
        For i = firstNonEmptyRow + 1 To lastRowSource ' Start from the row after the header
            accountKey = wsSource.Cells(i, 3).Value ' Use the value in the 3rd column as the key
            If accountDict.exists(accountKey & yearValue) Then
                accountDict(accountKey & yearValue) = accountDict(accountKey & yearValue) + wsSource.Cells(i, yearValue).Value
            Else
                accountDict.Add accountKey & yearValue, wsSource.Cells(i, yearValue).Value
                If yearValue = yearColumn Then ' Only add unique jurisdictions for the initial year column
                    uniqueJurisdictions.Add accountKey
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next yearValue
    
    
    
    ' Set the ajes worksheet
    Set wsAjes = wbSource.Sheets("ajes")
    
    Dim exists As Boolean
    Dim item As Variant
    
    headerRow = 1
    ajesLastRow = wsAjes.Cells(wsAjes.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    For ajesRow = headerRow + 1 To ajesLastRow
        Dim ajesJurisdiction As Variant
        ajesJurisdiction = wsAjes.Cells(ajesRow, 3).Value
        
        ' Check if the jurisdiction starts with "§"
        If Left(ajesJurisdiction, 1) = "§" Then
            ' Check if jurisdiction is already in the collection
            exists = False
            For Each item In uniqueJurisdictions
                If item = ajesJurisdiction Then
                    exists = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next item
            
            ' If not found, add it to the collection
            If Not exists Then
                uniqueJurisdictions.Add ajesJurisdiction
            End If
        End If
    Next ajesRow

    
    ' Set the Categorized Expenses worksheet
    Set wsCE = wbSource.Sheets("Categorized Expenses")
    Dim exists1 As Boolean
    Dim item1 As Variant
    
    headerRow = 1
    CELastRow = wsCE.Cells(wsCE.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    For CERow = headerRow + 1 To CELastRow
        Dim CEJurisdiction As Variant
        CEJurisdiction = wsCE.Cells(CERow, 1).Value
        
        ' Check if the jurisdiction starts with "§"
        If Left(CEJurisdiction, 1) = "§" Then
            ' Debug output to check values
            Debug.Print "CEJurisdiction: " & CEJurisdiction
            
            ' Check if jurisdiction is already in the collection
            exists1 = False
            For Each item1 In uniqueJurisdictions
                If item1 = CEJurisdiction Then
                    exists1 = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next item1
            
            ' If not found, add it to the collection
            If Not exists1 Then
                uniqueJurisdictions.Add CEJurisdiction
            End If
        End If
    Next CERow
        

    ' Loop through the unique jurisdictions and map them to the target columns
    For Each jurisdiction In uniqueJurisdictions
        ' Adjust the column mappings below as per your requirements
        wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 1).Value = jurisdiction & "_Average" ' Name 1
        wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 2).Value = jurisdiction & "_Average" ' Name 2
        wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 3).Value = "All" ' Jurisdiction
        wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 4).Value = "AverageBalance" ' Type
        wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 5).Value = "None_All" ' JurisFactor
        wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 6).Value = "" ' Rate_Element
        wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 7).Value = companyName ' Company
        wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 8).Value = projectName ' Project
        wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 9).Value = "" ' Rate
        wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 10).Value = "inputs" ' Step

        ' Write the sum for the yearInput
        Dim colOffset As Integer
        colOffset = 0
        wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 11 + colOffset).Value = accountDict(jurisdiction & yearInput)
        wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 12 + colOffset).Value = accountDict(jurisdiction & prevYear)

        ' Check if yearMode is multiple years
        If yearMode = vbYes Then
            ' Write the sums for each subsequent year without leaving gaps
            For Each yearValue In yearColumns
                If yearValue <> yearInput Then
                     wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 11 + colOffset).Value = accountDict(jurisdiction & yearValue)
                    colOffset = colOffset + 1
                End If
            Next yearValue
        End If

        ' Now find and extract the value from the "ajes" tab for the same jurisdiction
        ' Find the first non-empty row to determine the header row in "ajes"
        headerRow = 1
        ajesLastRow = wsAjes.Cells(wsAjes.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        Do While WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsAjes.Rows(headerRow)) = 0 And headerRow < ajesLastRow
            headerRow = headerRow + 1
        Loop

        ' Find the columns with the specified year in the header in "ajes"
        yearCol1 = 0
        yearCol2 = 0
        For i = 1 To wsAjes.Cells(headerRow, wsAjes.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If wsAjes.Cells(headerRow, i).Value = yearInput Then
                If yearCol1 = 0 Then
                    yearCol1 = i
                Else
                    yearCol2 = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        
        ' Initialize variables for summing ajes values
        Dim yearSumA As Double
        Dim yearSumB As Double
        
        ' Reset the sums for the jurisdiction
        yearSumA = 0
        yearSumB = 0

        ' Loop through "ajes" tab to find the jurisdiction and calculate the value
        For ajesRow = headerRow + 1 To ajesLastRow
            If wsAjes.Cells(ajesRow, 3).Value = jurisdiction Then ' Assuming jurisdiction is in column 3
                yearSumA = yearSumA + wsAjes.Cells(ajesRow, yearCol1).Value ' Accumulate yearCol1 value
                yearSumB = yearSumB + wsAjes.Cells(ajesRow, yearCol2).Value ' Accumulate yearCol2 value
            End If
        Next ajesRow
        
    ' Calculate the difference after accumulating values
     ajesYearValue = yearSumA - yearSumB
          
     
    headerRow1 = 1
    yearColCE = 0
    For i = 1 To wsCE.Cells(headerRow1, wsCE.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If wsCE.Cells(headerRow1, i).Value = yearInput Then
            yearColCE = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Check if the year column was found
    If yearColCE = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Year column " & yearInput & " not found in CE sheet.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub ' Exit the procedure if not found
    End If
    
    ' Loop through CE sheet to find the jurisdiction and map the value
    For CERow = headerRow1 + 1 To CELastRow
        If wsCE.Cells(CERow, 1).Value = jurisdiction Then ' Assuming jurisdiction is in column 1 of CE
            CEYearValue = wsCE.Cells(CERow, yearColCE).Value ' Directly get value from yearColCE
            Exit For ' Exit loop once the value is found
        End If
    Next CERow
    
' Add ajesYearValue and CEYearValue to the existing value in Column 11
' wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 11).Value = wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 110).Value + ajesYearValue + CEYearValue
  
        ' Make Column A cells bold and add right and bottom borders
        With wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 2, 1)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With

        lastRowTarget = lastRowTarget + 1 ' Increment the target row counter
    Next jurisdiction

    ' Close the source workbook without saving
    wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub


I have tried initializing previous year my object but still of no use
    For Each yearValue In yearColumns
        For i = firstNonEmptyRow + 1 To lastRowSource ' Start from the row after the header
            accountKey = wsSource.Cells(i, 3).Value ' Use the value in the 3rd column as the key

            ' Add values for yearInput
            If yearValue = yearColumn Then
                If accountDict.exists(accountKey & yearInput) Then
                    accountDict(accountKey & yearInput) = accountDict(accountKey & yearInput) + wsSource.Cells(i, yearValue).Value
                Else
                    accountDict.Add accountKey & yearInput, wsSource.Cells(i, yearValue).Value
                    uniqueJurisdictions.Add accountKey ' Add jurisdiction for yearInput
                End If
            End If

            ' Add values for previous year (yearInput - 1)
            If yearValue = yearColumn - 1 Then
                If accountDict.exists(accountKey & prevYear) Then
                    accountDict(accountKey & prevYear) = accountDict(accountKey & prevYear) + wsSource.Cells(i, yearValue).Value
                Else
                    accountDict.Add accountKey & prevYear, wsSource.Cells(i, yearValue).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next yearValue


yearColumns.Add j Stores all year columns starting from the yearInput column. So  If yearValue = yearColumn - 1 Then will never be true. Maybe you need For j = yearColumn -1 To wsSource.Cells(firstNonEmptyRow, wsSource.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column Just a guess.

Separate comment:  That wall of dimensions is a bit crazy.  You don't use the majority of those for some time and though it is working in this project, it may behoove you to start dimensioning at usage, which is sometimes enough to see errors related to type.
